# iOS SHA512 hash rounds result different from PHP

Tags: php, ios, hash, sha512

Aim is to run 5000 rounds of `CC_SHA512` in an iOS app and get the same result of 5000 rounds `open_ssl_digest($passkey, 'sha512')` in php. I have found this code on stackoverflow:

```
-(NSString*) sha512:(NSString*)input {
    const char *cstr = [input cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cstr length:input.length];

    uint8_t digest[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

    CC_SHA512(data.bytes, data.length, digest);

    NSMutableString* output = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];

    for(int i = 0; i < CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
        [output appendFormat:@"%02x", digest[i]];

    return output;

}
```

and running the whole code 5000 times works in giving the same results as openssl_digest, but I was thinking of making it more efficient by inserting this loop after the first hash and before creating the `NSMutableString`:

```
 //do it 4999 more times
    for (int i=0; i<4999; i++)
        CC_SHA512(digest, CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH, digest)
```

But this gives a different hash.

Comment: you're passing in digest twice in last example, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, a typo! Thanks for highlighting it. I've updated the code. I was testing it with 2 rounds and it still didn't match with 2 rounds on php side.